# i want to find out control name using its id

Tags: javascript, html

i have crated a text-box, which has an id, i want to know, is it possible to find out control name using getElementbyId.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            var a = document.getElementById('first').type;
            document.write(a);
        </script>
        <input type="text" id="first"></input>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The control you defined has no name.

Comment: You can try `a.getAttribute('type')`;

Comment: what you mean by control name? you want to know what kind of control it is(eg:input, li,select, button etc )? or you want to read the property of the element(eg:name, id, class etc)?

Comment: `document.getElementById('first').name`, but in your case it will be empty string

Comment: @Gilson PJ  i want to know what kind of control it is,plz help

Comment: have you gone through the link? use 'nodeName'

Comment: yes i got the solution..thanks

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to find out control name using getElementbyId.

You need to [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) of the element and

```
var element = document.getElementById('first');
alert(element.getAttribute("type")); //alerts its type attribute
alert(element.getAttribute("name")); //alerts its name attribute
alert(element.nodeName); //alerts its name
```

full example

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<body>

<input type="text"  id="first" name="firstName">

 <script>
   var element = document.getElementById('first');
   alert(element.getAttribute("type"));
   alert(element.getAttribute("name"));
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Observe that script tag is after the text input tag since unless the tag is loaded onto the DOM, DOM API (`document.getElementById`) will not be able to pick it up.

Comment: thanks..it is working

Comment: Why `type="text/javascript" language="javascript"`?

Comment: @torazaburo removed it

Comment: Now can you remove `</input`?

Comment: i cannot find the control name with select and image

Comment: @AbhishekKumar didn't get you. what do you mean by control name with select and image?

Answer (score -1):

i made this fiddle as example:
https://jsfiddle.net/z0vdhp1m/

few posibble problems:
input tag is not paired

```
    <input .... />
```

it's more clear to acces via getAttribute('type') than .type, but should work anyway.

document.write doesn't work on jsfiddle so i didn't test that, but if you were just to print it, then i suggest:

```
          alert();
```

or

```
          console.log()
```

Comment: `input` tag does not require closing.